# Can you retrieve an item from a list using regex in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

The problem I am trying to solve is I need to identify one of the Azure subnets in a virtual network by part of it's name. This is so I can then later retrieve it's CIDR. I only know part beforehand such as "mgmt-1" or "egress-1". The actual name of the subnet is much longer but will end in something like that. This was my process:

I have the vnet name so I pull all subnets:

```
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "this" {
  name = local.vnet
  resource_group_name = "myrg"
}
```

Now what I wish I could do is this:

```
locals {
  mgmt_index = index(data.azurerm_virtual_network.this.subnets, "*mgmt-1")
  mgmt_subnet = data.azurerm_virtual_network.this.subnets[local.mgmt_index]
}
```

However index wants an exact match, not a regex. Is this possible to do? Perhaps a better way?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to directly look up a list item using a regex match, but you can use `for` expressions to apply arbitrary filters to a collection when constructing a new collection:

```
locals {
  mgmt_subnets = toset([
    for s in data.azurerm_virtual_network.this.subnets : s
    if can(regex(".*?mgmt-1", s.name))
  ])
}
```

In principle an expression like the above could match more than one object, so I wrote this to produce a set of objects that match.

If you expect that there will never be more than one object whose name matches the pattern then you can use Terraform's `one` function to assert that and then Terraform will check to confirm that there's no more than one element (returning an error if not) and then return that one value.

```
locals {
  mgmt_subnet = one([
    for s in data.azurerm_virtual_network.this.subnets : s
    if can(regex(".*?mgmt-1", s.name))
  ])
}
```

If the condition doesn't match any of the subnet objects then in the first case you'll have an empty set and in the second case you'll have the value `null`.

Comment: I had to change "s.name" to "s" since the subnets is just a list of strings but this seems to work great just as I needed. Thank you!